# Is it possible to send function from parent to hidden child component in ReactJs

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a parent component from which I would like to send function to my child component.

**ParentComponent.js**

```
export default class LandingPage extends React.Component {

    onSearchSubmit(term) {
      console.log(term);
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
          <div>

            <div className = "admin" >
            <SearchBar onSubmit = {this.onSearchSubmit}
            /> 
            </div>
             ....
```

**ChildComponent.js**

```
export default class SearchBar extends React.Component{

    state = {term: ''};

    onFormSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.props.onSubmit(this.state.term);
    };

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="container">

                    <div className="searchBar mt-5">
                        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                            <div className="form-group">
                            <label for="search">Image search</label>
                                <input 
                                    type="text" 
                                    className="form-control" 
                                    placeholder="Search..." 
                                    value = {this.state.term}
                                    onChange={e => this.setState({term: e.target.value})}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I'm sending function to my child component so I could get input from user using search bar back to parent component. It works fine if child component is displayed and used on parent component.

But if I would like to approach my child component in a way that I hide it from parent component with CSS:

```
.admin{
      display: none;
    }
```

and access it like `http://localhost:3000/bar` and type text in my search bar there I am getting following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.onSubmit is not a function
```

Is it possible to send data this way using ReactJs or is there any other way to send data to child component without displaying child component in parent?

**UPDATE - WORKING SOLUTION**

I added parent component for both of my pages.

I have changed structure of my app in that way.

Before my app was structured in way that my `LandingPage.js` was a parent to `SearchBar.js`.

[image]

That's why I couldn't make communication between them work in way I wanted. I was trying to hack it by hiding search bar from my landing page and trying to send data from `http://localhost:3000/searchbar` to `http://localhost:3000/` without any luck and getting errors.

After I structured my app tp look like this:

[image]

I was able to send data between `LandinPage.js` and `SearchBar.js`.

**App.js** looked like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return(

    <div>
      <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage} />
      <Route path="/admin" component={Admin}/>
      <Route path="/posts" component={Post} />
      <Route path="/categories" component={Categories} />
      <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
      <Route path="/details" component={Details} />
      <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />

      <Route path="/weatherapp" component={weatherApp} />
      <Route path="/bar" component={SearchBar}/>
    </div>
  )
 }
}
```

To make `App.js` as parent have changed it to look like this:

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        articalName: "Landing page"
    };

}

onSearchSubmit = term => {
  console.log(term);
}

  render(){
    return(

    <div>
      <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage} />
      <Route path="/admin" component={ () => 
        <Admin 
          title={this.state.articalName}

          />}  
      />
      <Route path="/posts" component={Post} />
      <Route path="/categories" component={Categories} />
      <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
      <Route path="/details" component={Details} />
      <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />

      <Route path="/weatherapp" component={weatherApp} />
      <Route path="/bar" component={ () => 
        <SearchBar 
          onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit}

          />}  
         />
    </div>
  )
  }
}
```

I used routes to send my data from parent to child. This example uses React Router 4. I wanted to use only ReactJs but I guess good solution would be also using Redux.

Comment: please read this for your detailed answer https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Comment: @AbdulBasit I have read it but there is no answer for my question.

Comment: How are you able to search when you are making it display:none?

Comment: @Shad I understand that issue but how could I hide or not display child component in parent but separate? And still use it correctly?

Comment: Well so, basically, if I understand you correctly you are now making them kinda like siblings?

Comment: @Shad Well it's like I have landing page (parent) and admin page (child). On landing page I have all informations for users and on admin page as admin I log in and make all changes to informations and display it on landing page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not want a parent-child relationship between both the components, how about making them as siblings and add a parent component for both of them!

With that any search made in the SearchBar component you can pass it to the new parent and from that to the earlier considered parent.

Comment: But if I have one parent to those two I would still need to display them on same page right? On that new parent page? To be able to send them data... And I want to display them separately.. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Well, you could apply conditional rendering then. Add another state to parent, check the state and render accordingly.

Comment: I have just read the docs about it and I manage to hide my component. But still when I go to `http://localhost:3000/bar` and type there in my search bar I have same error `Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.onSubmit is not a function` do you know why?

Comment: Did you add a new parent for both of them and then applied conditional rendering based on the state as I said ?

Please post your updated code

Comment: I have updated my question with solution that worked. Please check it! I listened to your advice and applied parent for both of my components. I didn't used  conditional rendering instead I have used routes to send data between pages. Thanks for help!